# Mongoose not registering model

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript, mongoose

I am currently using AngularJS with Express-Jade and Mongoose with Coffeescript. The directory structure is split into Model View Controller.

This is the post.coffee in model

```
mongoose    = require("mongoose")
Schema  = mongoose.Schema

postSchema  = new Schema(
  title:
    type: String
    default: ""
    trim: true

  body:
    type: String
    default: ""
    trim: true
)

postSchema.path("title").validate ((title) ->
  title.length > 0
), "Post title cannot be blank"

postSchema.path("body").validate ((body) ->
  body.length > 0
), "Post body cannot be blank"

Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema)
```

And this is post.coffe in controller

```
mongoose = require("mongoose")
Post = mongoose.model("Post")
# _ = require("underscore")

# GET
exports.posts = (req, res) ->
  pList = Post.find
  posts = []
  pList.forEach (post, i) ->
    posts.push
      id: i
      title: post.title
      text: post.text.substr(0, 50) + "..."

  res.json posts: posts
```

And this snippet is from the app.coffee

```
# Bootstrap models
models_path = __dirname + "/models"
model_files = fs.readdirSync(models_path)
model_files.forEach (file) ->
  require models_path + "/" + file
```

However, the post.coffee in controller is throwing me an error:
    MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Post"

I know that this error can be solved by adding Post = mongoose.model("Post") in post.coffee in controller. However, is it possible to have this "Post" variable declared globally?

Comment: Make sure that the file which declares the model (`mongoose.model("Post", postSchema)`) is require'd *before* you try to retrieve the model (`mongoose("Post")`).

Comment: However, is it possible to have this "Post" variable declared globally?

Comment: Well, you could use `global.Post = mongoose.model(...)` to declare it, and `global.Post` to use it elsewhere, but that's bad practice as it makes maintaining and understanding your code more difficult.

Comment: What i noticed was other variables such as the socket object in socket = require('./routes/socket.js') is being called in controller scripts but the error says that socket is not defined. Hence i was hoping that it could be declared globally.

Comment: Undefined variables are coding errors :) So instead of declaring something globally, it's better to find out *why* isn't undefined when you expect it to be defined.

Comment: FWIW, `pList = Post.find` isn't going to work either. I think you expect that the `find` method will return an array of results, but it won't (because it's an asynchronous method, you're going to need to pass it a callback function: `Post.find (err, results) ->`)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

coffeescript was updated about a month ago

your code should look like this (i.e)

```
postSchema  = new Schema {
  title: {
    type: String
    default: ""
    trim: true
  },

  body:{
    type: String
    default: ""
    trim: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesnt work. module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema) doesnt seem to work globally

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to export the Post schema within the Post.coffee file. Try adding

```
module.exports = Post
```

at the end of the file inside the model folder.

Comment: It is still not working. When i register the schema via mongoose.model("Post",postSchema"), is it globally registered? Or can it be that the model script did not even run?

Comment: Here is a sample of how to make sure everything is exported properly: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/tree/master/examples/express/connection-sharing.

Comment: Is it possible to have it exported globally? E.g. mongoose = require("mongoose") in app.coffee and i can access mongoose from other scripts other than app.coffee. Thanks a bunch!